# How to make a vertical oval type of shape div?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to create an oval shape like the one below but failing

Also is there any way to insert an image inside this oval shaped css? that's my main objective.

[My Demo](https://jsbin.com/nugudoreva/edit?html,css,output)

```css
#oval {
  margin: 0px 0 10 02px;
  background: black;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px / 70px;
  border-radius: 50px / 50px;
  border-top-left-radius: 150px;
  border-top-right-radius: 150px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 150px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 150px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="oval_parent">
    <div id="oval"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider SVG as mask and you can easily obtain this shape.

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1074/800/800) center/cover;
  -webkit-mask:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'  viewBox='0 0 64 78' ><path d='M0 39 C0 61 8 78 32 78 C56 78 64 61 64 39 C64 19 56 0 32 0 C8 0 0 19 0 39 Z' /></svg>") 0 / 100% 100%;
          mask:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'  viewBox='0 0 64 78' ><path d='M0 39 C0 61 8 78 32 78 C56 78 64 61 64 39 C64 19 56 0 32 0 C8 0 0 19 0 39 Z' /></svg>") 0 / 100% 100%;
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:121%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="width:150px;"></div>
```

below the SVG I am using and if you want to edit it here is a good online tool where you simply need to append the path into the url to start editing: [https://jxnblk.github.io/paths/?d=M0 39 C0 61 8 78 32 78 C56 78 64 61 64 39 C64 19 56 0 32 0 C8 0 0 19 0 39 Z](https://jxnblk.github.io/paths/?d=M0%2039%20C0%2061%208%2078%2032%2078%20C58%2078%2064%2061%2064%2039%20C64%2019%2056%200%2032%200%20C8%200%200%2019%200%2039%20Z)

```html
<svg
  xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
  viewBox='0 0 64 78'
  width='100' >
  <path d='M0 39 
           C0 61 8 78 32 78 
           C56 78 64 61 64 39 
           C64 19 56 0 32 0 
           C8 0 0 19 0 39 Z' />
</svg>
```

Comment: really great. I tried with svg and it didn't work because I didn't add `::before`. I didn't know this and I don't understand why we must add it. also, how did you calculate `121%`?

Comment: @dgknca the before is not needed, you can simply set the height and it will work: https://jsfiddle.net/7xavjL9h/. I am using it with the padding trick to have a generic solution and maintain the same ratio. The 121% comes from the image posted in the question (1020/840)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @dgknca ,
using your clipreact i tried and adding with border-radius did the job ,
Update : Problem , the width and top height looks good but the top curve is litter flattened in my requirement image and this one is too oval from top any help ?

```css
#oval {
  margin: 0px 0 10 02px;
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/536/354");
  -moz-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px / 70px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  clip-path: ellipse(50% 50% at 50% 50%);
  width: 82.4px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="oval"></div>
```

Comment: the border radius will do nothing, only the clip-path is doing the job here and still not exactly like the picture of the question

Comment: and the clip-path you are using will produce the same result as border radius: https://jsfiddle.net/e3vLjnty/

Comment: @TemaniAfif i just noticed you are correct, the width and top height looks good but the top curve is litter flattened in my requirement image and this one is too oval from top

Comment: @TemaniAfif can u make a border radius to it ? i tried using css its not working