# In css, how to create a bulging square

Tags: css

Is it possible to achieve this in pure css, without requiring to use an embedded SVG in your page.

Obvs `border-radius: 10px` doesn't quite cut it.

[image]

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62692459/8620333

Comment: Whoever closed the question, the related questions you specified do not satisfy my requirements. The accepted answer resolves it.

Comment: the accepted answer is far from achieving what you are showing to us. You may need to update you question then.

Comment: my answer is a bit better now @TemaniAfif - I have changed some values, and now it is a lot better

Comment: @TemaniAfif describe how its 'far from achieving' the desired result. Oh and what do you think "without requiring to use an embedded SVG in your page" means?

Comment: if you read the duplicates you will find solutions with only css ;) if you read them of course.

Comment: @TemaniAfif the link you posted here is far from achieving the shape I posted.

Comment: the link I posted is only *related*. I did it before I find the duplicates that achieve perfectly your shape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick example where we change the top and bottom `border-radius`es. We can use the other value as a weird kind of height thing which will control the height of our radius.

```css
.box {
    background: #62f;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 50% / 10px;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">8</div>
```

Now then, we can use the `::before` and `::after` selector to make two of these:

```css
.box::after {
    background: #62f;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 50% / 10px;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1.75em;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 8px;
}

.box::before {
    background: #62f;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px / 50%;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 1.75em;
    height: 1em;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">8</div>
```

Now then, I hear you ask, what about our 8? Where has it gone? Well, my friends, it has actually gone behind our weird square. We can wrap it in a span and style this to fix this.

```css
.box::after {
    background: #62f;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 50% / 10px;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1.75em;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 8px;
}

.box::before {
    background: #62f;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px / 50%;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 1.75em;
    height: 1em;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 2px;
}

.box > span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 32px;
    left: 36px;
    z-index: 5;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><span>8</span></div>
```

We can also swap a few numbers around to make it even more perfect as well:

```css
.box::after {
    background: #62f;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 50% / 20px;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1.75em;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 8px;
}

.box::before {
    background: #62f;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 20px / 50%;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 1.7em;
    height: 1em;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 2px;
}

.box > span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 32px;
    left: 36px;
    z-index: 5;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><span>8</span></div>
```

Comment: This is not the same shape as example. The edges are straight in your example where they should be rounded at a larger radius than the corners.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to edit my example with a better solution

Comment: There we go, @digout, I have updated example!

Comment: Kind of hacky, but it does achieve the desired result!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```css
.square{
  height:80px;
  width:80px;
  background:blue;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius:2rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  opacity: 0.5;
  box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="square">8</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the reason for the white box-shadow?

Comment: This is not the same shape as example. The edges are straight in your example where they should be rounded at a larger radius than the corners.